# How to pass a member function as pthread start_routine?

Tags: c++

I got that:

```
 void* xxx::yyy(void* ThreadIdPtr)
```

And now I do that:

```
pthread_create( &tp, NULL, xxx::yyy, (void*) &i);
```

but compile error:

```
error: argument of type 'void* (xxx::)(void*)' does not match 
'void* (*)(void*)'
```

How to pass it correctly?

Comment: I suggest you read about [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).

Comment: As for your question, the simple answer is that you *cant't* use a non-static member function. All non-static member functions have an implicit and hidden "zeroth" argument that is the `this` pointer. A C function such as `pthread_create` doesn't know about that, and so can't pass it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointer to a member function is *not* a pointer to a function. The two just aren't the same. Trying to use a pointer to a member function as if it were a pointer to a function...well, about the best you could hope for would be for it to crash quickly and cleanly.

Although it's probably not technically defined behavior, there's at least a reasonable chance that you can use a pointer to a *static* member function. You can then pass a pointer to an object as the parameter, and it can invoke the proper member function of that object.

Other than that, you can use a normal function like pthreads expects, and be done with it.

Comment: A pointer to a `static` member function will work just fine and is perfectly valid and using it in such a context is defined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass member function to a function that takes functor, you should do it this way:

```
MyClass a;
some_function(&MyClass::MyMethod, a);
```

Every function in stdlib that takes pointer to function have overload to take member function. If you want to pass it in std::thread cotr, do it this way:

```
std::thread(&MyClass::MyMethod, a, arg1, arg2);
```